# Why is my array not adding numbers?

Tags: c#, arrays, random

Here is my code:

```
namespace Exercise6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            OtherClass aTable = new OtherClass(); //instantiate class

            Console.WriteLine("How many rows do you want your two-dimensional array to be?");
            aTable.SRows = Console.ReadLine(); //reads input for how many rows that the user would like
            aTable.IntRows = int.Parse(aTable.SRows); //convert rows to int

            Console.WriteLine("Thanks you! How many columns would you like your two-dimensional arry to be?");
            aTable.SColumns = Console.ReadLine(); //reads input for how many columns that the user would like
            aTable.IntColumns = int.Parse(aTable.SColumns); //convert columns to int

            //set two dimensional array based upon the size that the user has requested

            int[ , ] array = new int[aTable.IntColumns, aTable.IntRows];

            Random randomArray = new Random(); //call to random class to ask for random numbers

            for (int i = 0; i < aTable.IntColumns; i++) //columns
            {
                array[i, 0] = randomArray.Next(0, 100); //for every value in each column, insert a random number
            }

            for (int y = 0; y < aTable.IntRows; y++) //rows
            {
                array[y, 0] = randomArray.Next(0, 100);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(array);


        }
    }
}

namespace Exercise6
{
    class OtherClass
    {
        private string sRows;

        public string SRows { get; set; }

        private int intRows;

        public int IntRows { get; set; }

        private string sColumns;

        public string SColumns { get; set; }

        private int intColumns;

        public int IntColumns { get; set; }

    }
}
```

But, I can't figure out why my output, which should just be my array, would say:

> System.Int32[,]

Did it not add the random numbers from the for loops to my array?

Thanks in advance for all of your help!

Comment: Side note: you are setting only small number of elements to random values in that array (only first row)... may or may not be what you actually want.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Once he figures out how to print the array values hopefully he'll be able to get to that.

Answer (score 4):

When you call `Console.WriteLine(array)`, it calls `array`'s `ToString` method. Since arrays don't provide any better implementation, the [default `ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) is called, which just returns its type: `System.Int32[,]`. You need to specify yourself how to turn that array into a `string`, e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < aTable.IntColumns; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < aTable.IntRows; j++)
    {
        if (j != 0)
            Console.Write(", ");
        Console.Write(array[i, j]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Writes something like:

```
0, 1, 2
3, 4, 5
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe your actual question is: why `ToString` on most types return just type name, unlike `String.ToString` which returns value.

Most classes do not override `ToString` method and as result get default behavior which is just output type name.

In your particular case you probably want to iterate over all elements and print them.

Answer (score 1):

Console.WriteLine(array); is calling array.ToString().
 By default this is printing the object Type.

> Returns a string that represents the current object. (Inherited from
>   Object.)

see [Array MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/system.array.aspx)

You need give out every entry of the array manually. This can be done with a loop, see the linked article for a example.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're writing the `Array` object.  You need to write each individual element in the array out, or override `ToString()` in your array.

Comment: You cannot override the `ToString` behavior of `Array`.  It's not a type he has control over.